# Why do I keep getting errors when submitting my data to my database?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

Currently my problem is, I am trying to upload data to my database when a user fills out a modal. Upon hitting submit this data should upload to the database and display on the table. When the user hits submit, I get the error, "ERROR: INVALID INPUT". Below is where the error is coming from:

```
if (isset($_POST['create'])){
  if(isset($_POST['createdby']) && isset($_POST['itemold']) && isset($_POST['itemnew'])
    && isset($_POST['startdatetime']) && isset($_POST['enddatetime']) && isset($_POST['approver1']) 
    && isset($_POST['approver2']) && isset($_POST['approver3']) && isset($_POST['approver4']) 
    && isset($_POST['approver5']) && isset($_POST['approver6']) && isset($_POST['approver7']) 
    && isset($_POST['approver8']) && isset($_POST['note']) && isset($_POST['file']) && isset($_POST['docname'])){
    
    echo json_encode(createFile($_POST['createdby'], $_POST['itemold'], $_POST['itemnew'], 
    $_POST['startdatetime'], $_POST['enddatetime'], $_POST['approver1'], $_POST['approver2'], 
    $_POST['approver3'], $_POST['approver4'], $_POST['approver5'], $_POST['approver6'],
    $_POST['approver7'], $_POST['approver8'], $_POST['note'], $_POST['file'], $_POST['docname']));
    
  } else {
    echo "ERROR: INVALID INPUT";
  }
```

Below is my ajax and where the data is submitted:

```
//Data To Pass Through Ajax Request
  let formData = new FormData();
  formData.append('create', 1);
  formData.append('createdby', createdby);
  formData.append('itemold', itemold);
  formData.append('itemnew', itemnew);
  formData.append('startdatetime', startdatetime);
  formData.append('enddatetime', enddatetime);
  formData.append('approver1', approver1);
  formData.append('approver2', approver2);
  formData.append('approver3', approver3);
  formData.append('approver4', approver4);
  formData.append('approver5', approver5);
  formData.append('approver6', approver6);
  formData.append('approver7', approver7);
  formData.append('approver8', approver8);
  formData.append('note', note);
  formData.append('file', $('#create_file')[0].files[0]);
  formData.append('docname', docname);
  
  $.ajax({
    url: './ajax/submitData.ajax.php',
    type: 'POST',
    data: formData,
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(response) {
      if (response.success === 1){
        closeAndClearCreateModal();
        refreshData();
      } else {
        document.getElementById("errorMSGCreate").innerHTML = response.error;
      }
    }
  });
```

I don't know exactly what I am doing wrong. I have done this numerous times across my intranet page but never encounter this type of issue. So far I have looked at all my code to make sure all my variables are the same and that nothing is misspelled but nothing seems out of place and this is where I am confused. Am I calling the data wrong? Should I add something or what should I do?

If anyone needs anything else, let me know in the comments and I will add what is needed.

Comment: Seems like the next step would be to determine which piece(s) of your if-statement are returning false.

Comment: Just to let everyone know, the reason I was getting the following error above was because I was missing one table within my database that needed to be added to my ajax as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `dataType: 'json'` or convert form data to `json` using some library like: https://www.jqueryscript.net/form/form-data-json-object.html

Comment: Datatype is for the data being returned from the server. This issue is what's being passed to the server.